# Customizing ModelSerializer error message is being ignored

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-validation, django-serializer

This is my UserSerializer (I'm using the default Django User model):

```
class UserSerializer(SetCustomErrorMessagesMixin, serializers.ModelSerializer):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            super(UserSerializer, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs) # call the super() 
            for field in self.fields: # iterate over the serializer fields
                self.fields[field].error_messages['required'] = 'Enter a valid %s.'%field
                self.fields[field].error_messages['null'] = 'Enter a valid %s.'%field

                # class CharField(Field) errors
                self.fields[field].error_messages['blank'] = 'Enter a valid %s.'%field
                self.fields[field].error_messages['max_length'] = '%s cannot have more than {max_length} characters.'%field
                self.fields[field].error_messages['min_length'] = '%s cannot have less than {min_length} characters.'%field

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'password', 'email',)
```

The problem is, when a user inputs a username which is too long, the error message is

```
"Username is too long."
```

Where is this error message coming from? I overwrote the "max_length" error message in the code above, but it does not show it. When I delete this line from my UserSerialzer:

```
self.fields[field].error_messages['max_length'] = '%s cannot have more than {max_length} characters.'%field
```

then the error message is:

```
"Ensure this field has no more than 30 characters."
```

which makes sense beause it is coming from the CharField DRF source code here: https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/fields.py

But where is "Username is too long." coming from and how come it does not say "Username cannot have more than {max_length} characters." instead?

Comment: Where does `field` come from in your `__init__`?

Comment: @Ivan Sorry, when copy-pasting my code, I accidentally deleted this line: "for field in self.fields:". I edited my post and added the line now. Does it make more sense?

Comment: What versions of Django and DRF are you using?

Comment: Did you find where the message was coming from?

Comment: @Ivan I am using Django 1.8 and DRF 3.2.4. Your answer was correct, it was using the error message which came from MaxLengthValidator. My UserSerializer inherits from SetCustomErrorMessagesMixin and in that class the MaxLengthValidator was being overridden. But nonetheless, MaxLengthValidator is in fact what was showing up instead of "%s cannot have more than {max_length} characters.'%field"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem appears to be that DRF adds validators for fields during their construction and copies the error messages from field classes.

For example from `rest_framework.fields.CharField.__init__`:

```
if self.min_length is not None:
    message = self.error_messages['min_length'].format(min_length=self.min_length)
    self.validators.append(MinLengthValidator(self.min_length, message=message))
```

So at the moment you are overwriting the messages, they are already used in the validators.

I think you can just create a `yourapp.fields` module where you subclass DRF serializer fields and override their `default_error_messages`, like so:

```
from rest_framework import fields

class CharField(fields.CharField):

    default_error_messages = {
        # Your messages
    }
```

And then just switch the module you import fields from.

You might also want to override `__init__`s to add field names in messages.

Comment: I see what you mean. Quick question though: Just to clarify, when I am overriding the error messages with: "self.fields[field].error_messages['max_length'] = '%s cannot have more than {max_length} characters.'%field", what I am doing is overriding the DRF Serializer field validators? And when I use the code you posted, I am overriding the Django model field validators?

Comment: No, I override the serialzer fields (I even have an import in my code that indicates that). Also, if you want messages with field names, you might want to override `__init__`s also.